# Abstracting function parameter format and its effects on performance?

Tags: c++, performance, abstraction, calling-convention, vm-implementation

I am developing a VM and I would like to make it possible to call compiled functions. However, because every function may end up having a different signature, my plan is to generalize all calls to 2 possible scenarios - a call for function with no return and no parameters, and a call to a function which takes one `void *` parameter.

The plan is to use it similarly to `thiscall` - all parameters are properly aligned at the location of the passed pointer and parameters are retrieved through indirection. Shouldn't be slower than reading them from the stack, at least IMO.

So instead of:

`int foo(int a, int b) { return a+b; }`

I can have something like:

```
void foo2(void *p) {
   *(int*)p = *(int*)(p + 4) + *(int*)(p + 8);
}
```

So my question is what could potentially go wrong using this approach? What I can tell right away is it works "in the dark" so it would be crucial to calculate the offsets correctly. It is also a little inconvenient since all the temporaries need to be provided by the user. Assuming my VM compiler will deal with those two issues, I am mostly concerned about performance - I don't want to create a normal function and for each normal function a `void *` wrapper - I would like to directly use that convention for all functions, so I can't help but wonder how good of a job will the compiler do of inlining the functions when used in compiled code? Are there going to be any other possible performance implications I am overlooking (excluding `__fastcall` which will use one more register and one less indirection)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running a few benchmarks I'd say the compiler does a pretty good job of optimizing similar pointer functions. The `void *` function is just as fast as the `add` function and the regular `+` operator.

It seems that this convention will be useful to provide the necessary calling abstraction without hurting optimizations and overall performance. The only sacrifice is safety, which may or may not be a primary concern depending on the application context.

Answer (score 0):

Performance wise (and ease of use) you will probably be best off with `cdecl` - everything goes onto the stack. The C standard allows you to specify function prototypes with arbitrary arguments

```
typedef void (__cdecl * function_with_any_parameters)();
```

You will have to make sure to define all functions that you wish to invoke as:

```
void __cdecl f(type1 arg1, type2 arg2, type3 arg3); // any amount of arguments
```

And just invoke them with the right amount of arguments:

```
f(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
```

---

If you wish to go through a single pointer then you do have extra overhead: the one pointer. The easiest way would be to define all functions as accepting a pointer to an anonymous struct:

```
void f(struct {type1 a; type2 b;} * args);
```

Then you can invoke the function with a pointer to the appropriate struct to avoid any misalignments.

```
struct {type1 a; type2 b;} args = {arg1, arg2};
f(&args);
```

You are effectively implementing `cdecl` on your own.

Comment: According to what I've read `cdecl` won't put the pointer on a register, it will put it on the stack, so I will have to use indirection to get the pointer and against to access a value.

Comment: Also, consider that the assembly generated for "manual" offsets is equal to the code generated if the function pretends it is a struct with member fields, same code instruction for instruction.

Comment: @user2341104 You didn't specify what target architecture you are working on. At least on x86 `cdecl` decrements the `*sp` register to point to the stack arguments. Also maybe I misunderstood your question I believed you wanted some degree of ease of programming.

Comment: I won't be writing any of that code, it will all be generated. I am only concerned with performance and "inline"-ability of the `void *` "convention". Also, the plan is to work on most popular hardware, e.g. x86 and ARM.

Comment: @user2341104 I would imagine if `args` is accessed frequently enough in the function that the optimizer would assign a register to that during register allocation.